Why Doesn't $scope Work as a Selector, but a Class Name Selector Does?
I'm trying to use $scope as a selector in my code, but it's not working as expected. However, when I use the class name selector, like ".element-class", it works fine. I'm specifically trying to use $scope, but I'm not sure what's causing the issue. Can anyone explain why $scope isn't working and how I can fix it?
"use strict";
(function ($) {
  const $window = $(window);
  $window.on('elementor/frontend/init', function () {
    elementorFrontend.hooks.addAction('frontend/element_ready/widget', function ($scope) {
      const settings = $scope.data('settings');
      if (settings && settings.codexse_scroll === 'yes') {
          lax.init();
          lax.addDriver('scrollY', function () {
            return window.scrollY;
          });
          lax.addElements($scope, {
            scrollY: {
              opacity: [
                ["elInY", "elCenterY", "elOutY"],
                [0, 1, 0],
              ]
            }
          });
      }
    });
  });
})(jQuery);

I want to use $scope as the selector.

What specifically isn't working with $scope? Is it $scope.data('settings'); that's causing issues? lax.addElements($scope, { that's not working as expected? Both lines?

lax.addElements($scope,

I think the issue is with the lax JavaScript plugin, which is causing $scope to not work. Even if I use $('body').find('.element'), it still doesn't work.

I don't see the docs for lax saying that you're able to pass a jQuery object as the selector argument. It does mention that you can pass an elements option, so maybe worth trying that (looking at the source code, it seems to look for domElements so maybe try that if it doesn't work)
